# what's the range of the formatted output of `cout`

Tags: c++

In my program, there will be two lines of output: numbers in the first line are integers less than 1000; numbers in the second line are floats between 0 and 10. The format of the output I want is like:

[right format](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DYNgc.png)

and here is how I try (all outputs are the last four lines):
[case 1 - 5](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9K5i3.jpg)

1. output without format; in the picture we can see the numbers that should be printed
2. line 1 without format and line 2 with format
   numbers in line 1; only the first one is right, and the number that is bigger than 100 is in scientific notation
3. both lines with format
   just like case 2, and `<<setw(3)<<setfill('0')` seems only works for one time to change 43 to 043, and then it won't work any more
4. With `noshowpoint` added. If i print `*(p + 2)`alone, it always prints `118`with or without format. But if I print `*(p + 2)` in the `for` loop, the output is still `1.2e+002` except for the first one. But if I print the number `118` directly, the output is right.

So, which part of my code is wrong? And what is the right way to output the answer in right format?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, for the third, you set `showpoint` but never unset it with the `noshowpoint`, hence the next lines issue.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>
using namespace std;

int main() {
    double x[4]= {43.0,118.0,9.0,5.0};
    double y[4] = {9.5, 9.0, 8.5, 8.0};
    // your code goes here
    for (int i=0; i< 4; i++)
    {
      cout<<noshowpoint<<setprecision(3)<<setw(3)<<setfill('0')<<(x[i]) <<" ";
      cout<<showpoint<<setprecision(2)<<y[i] << endl;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

gives the desired output.

Just pay attention that you set the `showpoint` and `setprecision`  manipulators for stream, not for the single output.

Comment: I added `noshowpoint` but there is still a problem. It is showed in case 4. thank you very much.

Comment: Try to add the noshowpoint only for the third case, as per my example. You are adding 118 to the output and setw expires on it.

Comment: yes i tried this [but it doesn't work, the last one](http://i.stack.imgur.com/9K5i3.jpg)

Comment: I was able to reproduce it, your first parameter is double, by setting `setprecision(2)` in second output you change the way it is printed. See the updated code.

Comment: yes that's right. `setprecision` caused the problem rather than `showpoint`. Thank you very much :)

Answer (score 2):

Indeed, not all IO Formatting Manipulators are *persistent*. Some of them, like `std::setw` only take effect on the next operation, then they expire. There's nothing "wrong" with your code; you just need to use the manipulator again. Refer to your favourite C++ standard library documentation to check the persistence of each manipulator that you use.